# How can I track an sesClient email using a data.messageId

Tags: javascript, amazon-ses

I have written a Javascript prototype to send raw email from me@acme.com (validated) to popeye@gmail.com. This works. I next moved to another script to send a templated email using sendTemplatedEmailCommand. I don't get any errors. I get something like Success 0100018bc1fdebcc-b1f434c0-a698-423b-8b6b-87aaf17cc590-000000. The uuid part comes from data.messageId.

I never receive any mail at popeye@gmail.com. Does anyone know how I can track this issue down. The raw email that worked was not HTML. This method is using an HTML template that I created at AWS Management Console/SES.

```js
import { SendTemplatedEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
import { sesClient } from "./libs/sesClient.js";

async function sendTemplatedEmailCommand(sender, recipients, templateName, templateDataObject) {
    const templateData = JSON.stringify(templateDataObject);
    const params = {
        Source: sender,
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: recipients,
        },
        Template: templateName,
        TemplateData: templateData,
    };
    try {
        const data = await sesClient.send(new SendTemplatedEmailCommand(params));
        console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
    }
}

async function run() {
    await sendTemplatedEmailCommand(
        "me@acme.com",
        ["popeye@gmail.com"],
        "AgentTemplate",
        JSON.stringify({name: "Tom", owner: "Bob"}));
}

run();
```

I've also added a SNS topic and subscription for a "bounce" and I'm not getting a bounce either. It's like the try block runs the sendEmail method and no errors are caught, the console.log tells me "Success" and the data object return from the function has a messageId (unique). But, I have no indication that anything ever makes it to AWS SES.

I also checked TLS on my end, node, firewall ports, etc and then realized that my raw email test worked therefore, AWS did the TLS with me for that. So it's not TLS.

Any suggestions, opinions, help is greatly appreciated.